# How to enable output compression (gzip) on everything that goes out of my Ruby on rails on Mongrel/WEBrick Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gzip, mongrel, webrick

I am not sure this is the right place to ask this question, as answer to this may be coding solution or a config solution :) any way,

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.11 running on the Mongrel server. How do i enable the gzip compression on everything (views, data, JS, CSS etc.) that goes out of this server?

I tried google, and most responses say use apache:P but i donot have access to any other web server. There are no straight answers as to how to get webrick to do this.

Can anyone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the [Mongrel GZipFilter](http://rubydoc.info/gems/gzip_filter/0.2/GzipFilter).

Comment: Hi @Don, I am using procer over mongrel. I tried to make the change mentioned above in the mongrel2.conf file but it does not seem to be working. Could you please suggest how to make this work with procer?